# какой язык не является интерпретируемым

Tags: javascript, java, python

Какой из ниже перечисленных языков не является интерпретируемым.
10 баллов
• С++.
• Python.
• Perl.
• Java.
• JavaScript.
• Forth.

Comment: Вы в слове Google сделалии 12 опечаток и случайно набрали ruStackOverflow

Answer (score 4):

**C++**

В следующий раз попробуйте использовать google:
https://tproger.ru/translations/programming-concepts-compilation-vs-interpretation/
http://itmentor.by/articles/kompiliruemye-i-interpretiruemye-yazyki-programmirovaniya

Answer (score 0):

На сегодняшний день, ответ на этот вопрос уже неоднозначный.

Если вы имеете в виду — есть ли у языка отдельная стадия компиляции и распространяется ли программа в виде готового бинарного исполняемого файла, тогда, например, C++ неинтерпретируемый.

Если иметь в виду — исполняется ли код программы строчка за строчкой, или же среда исполнения парсит весь код и перед исполнением компилирует его во внутреннюю бинарную форму, а иногда во время исполнения оптимизирует и перекомпилирует его на ходу, тогда, например, ни JavaScript, ни Perl уже нельзя считать интерпретируемыми. Интерпретируемыми можно считать разве что некоторые пакетные файлы для оболочек.